# how to join two measurement of influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I want to join two different measurement of same database.how can join two measurement of same database with respect to timestamp in influxdb database.
I have checked with below things in influxdb:
select hosta.value + hostb.value
from cpu_load as hosta
inner join cpu_load as hostb
where hosta.host = 'hosta.influxdb.orb' and hostb.host = 'hostb.influxdb.org';

But may query is if the two measurement of same database with different name how can i join or how can i implement above query in my case?
consider below thing is my use case-
assume mydatabase is mydb
and there are two measurement one is cpu and another is network:

```
  {
        "measurement": "cpu",
        "tags": {
            "container": cont_name,                             
        },

        "fields": {
            "Value": 25.78,

        }
    }
    ] 
{
        "measurement": "network",
        "tags": {
            "container": cont_name,                             
        },

        "fields": {
            "Value": 96,

        }
    }
    ]
```

I want to merge above to measurement and want to get single measurement with both measurements information?

Is it possible to merge two measurements?

another issue:
select s1.value from "cpu" as s1
below error is coming:
ERR: error parsing query: found AS, expected ; at line 1, char 39?

Answer (score 2):

I also spent some time looking into this, and it seems that at InfluxDB version 1.6 this is not possible:

> Currently, there is no way to perform cross-measurement math or grouping. All data must be under a single measurement to query it together. InfluxDB is not a relational database and mapping data across measurements is not currently a recommended schema. See GitHub Issue #3552 for a discussion of implementing JOIN in InfluxDB.
>   – https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-do-i-query-data-across-measurements

The issue is being tracked in GitHub here: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3552

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** Is it possible to merge two measurements?
**A:** No. Cross measurement join is not possible through `influx`'s query engine until `v1.7.0` where you can use their new `flux` query language to do so.

**Reference:**

https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.7/guides/join

> Flux allows you to join on any columns common between two data streams
>   and opens the door for operations such as cross-measurement joins and
>   math across measurements.

Prior to `v1.7.0` the only way you can achieve `cross-measurement join` is through writing a script/program. E.g. Using a influxdb driver to read out the data and then manually merge the dataset yourself.

Comment: Math across measurements using Flux is only available as of version 1.8, not 1.7 https://ibb.co/P6StwWm
check the version in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

So this can be done in FluxQL, though it is not extremely straightforward.

The `v`variable is provided by Grafana according to current view.

Explanation: First get both tables and resample to the minimum required amount of data. Then set the `_measurement` field to match in the two tables. Finally, `union(...)` the two tables, and sort the union by `_time`. At this point maybe aggregate again and then pivot to create a table for each time step.

The `createEmpty: true` in `aggregateWindow(...)` makes sure you have one record for each time step, and then use `fill(...)` to fill in missing records with previous ones. This makes it so you dont need to deal with `null` records that

This worked for me:

```
import "math"
import "internal/debug"
    
slow = from(bucket: "test")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r._measurement == "slow"
  )
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with _measurement: "fast"}))
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: first, createEmpty: true)
  |> fill(usePrevious: true)

fast = from(bucket: "test")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r._measurement == "fast"
  )
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: true)
  |> fill(usePrevious: true)
  
union(tables: [fast, slow])
|> sort(columns: ["_time"])
|> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: first, createEmpty: false)
|> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
```